# How do I call a code image to use in HTML?

Tags: c#, html

I'm using this code to create a QR code (C#):

```
string text = "QRCode test";
            QRCodeGenerator qr = new QRCodeGenerator();
            QRCodeData data = qr.CreateQrCode(text, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
            QRCode code = new QRCode(data);
            
            Image img = code.GetGraphic(5);
```

Then I'm trying to insert it into an HTML like this (HTML):

```
<img src='{img}'>
```

I don't know how to do for the image to get to the code because from what I know the "src" only goes to the device or the internet.